# Adminer blank GUI elements running on mySQL 8

Tags: adminer

i am running **[Adminer 4.8.0](https://www.adminer.org)** on 2 machines:

my live production server: running mySQL **5.7.28**

my local development machine: running mySQL **8.0.23**

on the live server everything looks fine. on my local machine all of the engine/collation/row counts are all either blank or have question marks. see attached images:

[image: adminer_mysql5]
[image: adminer_mysql8]

Comment: I would ask this question on the adminer support forum, not here.

Comment: i did ask in the Adminer support forums. did not get any helpful responses. thought i would try my luck here. thought maybe others had see the same issue. thanks.

Comment: The problem is that SO is a programming Q/A site, not a general product support site. You would have to show the relevant section of adminer's code and provide a meaningful error message for your question to qualify for SO. Nobody here is going to debug adminer for you from scratch. It is also a possibility that this is a simple config issue with adminer, which is completely off topic here on SO.

Answer (score 1):

apologies to @Shadow and others if this was posted in the wrong place, but i did find a solution to this issue:

in the Adminer source, replace this:

`$R["Engine"]==($Zf=="pgsql"?"table":"InnoDB")`

with this:

`$R["Engine"]==(isset($Zf)&&$Zf=="pgsql"?"table":"InnoDB")`

details of the issue are [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/adminer/bugs-and-features/792/).

looking at the [GitHub ChangeLog](https://github.com/vrana/adminer/blob/master/changes.txt) this appears to be fixed in the next release.

hope this helps others. thanks.